# "Expected class or package" when using scala inner case class from java

Tags: scala

I have a scala class similar to the following:

```
case class Foo(a: String) {
  case class Bar(b: String)
}
```

I try to invoke this from java code as follows:

```
Foo f = Foo.apply("foo");
Bar b = f.Bar.apply("bar");
```

I receive a compilation error (in Intellij) with `f` underlined in the `Bar b =` statement with the message "Expected class or package". Does anyone know what the problem is with this? Intellij even suggests the above syntax with auto-complete.

Comment: I had a typo in the question originally (fixed it now). I did mean that I used `apply` there. The same error is there. Using the `new` syntax, there's an error that says "Cannot resolve symbol 'Bar'.

Answer (score 0):

You should not define case classes inside of each other, due to Java serialization issues: https://github.com/alexandru/scala-best-practices/blob/v0.4/sections/2-language-rules.md#217-should-not-define-case-classes-nested-in-other-classes

I recommend splitting them into separate case classes in the same package:

```
package flatclasses
case class Bar(b: String)
case class Foo(a: String)
```

and then changing the Java code:

```
Foo f = flatclasses.Foo.apply("foo");
Bar b = flatclasses.Bar.apply("bar");
```

Comment: This is only relevant if you need to work with Java's built-in serialization. By the same justification given, you also couldn't have a case class containing any non-serializable fields, or generic case classes which could be instantiated with non-serializable type parameters.

Comment: Good points. I can remove this answer if you don't think it's helpful.